# How to normally bind forms in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, validation

I have a template form, which I wrote from guides and they don't really work though.
I have several of models:

```
export class User {
  constructor(public userId?: UserId,
              public firstName?: String,
              public lastName?: String,
              public address?: Address) {
  }
}

export class Address {
  constructor(
    public street?: String,
    public city?: String,
    public zipCode?: String) {
  }
}
```

I have component:

```
Component({
  templateUrl: 'user.html'
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{
  user: User;
  userForm: NgForm;
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
```

And page itself:

```
<form novalidate #userForm="ngForm">


    <div class="form-group">

        <input required minlength="4" type="text"
               id="firstName"
               [(ngModel)]="user.firstName" name="firstName">
        <small *ngIf="!firstName.valid">Not valid!</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input required ng-minlength="4" type="text"
               id="lastName"
               [(ngModel)]="user.lastName" name="lastName">
    </div>

    <div ngModelGroup="user.address">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input required ng-minlength="4"
                   type="text"
                   id="address-house"
                   [(ngModel)]="user.address.address1" name="address.address1">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input required ng-minlength="4"
                       type="text"
                       id="zipCode"
                       [(ngModel)]="user.address.zipCode" name="address.zipCode">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input required ng-minlength="4"
                       type="text"
                       lass="form-control input-lg"
                       id="city"
                       [(ngModel)]="user.address.city" name="address.city">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <button type="button" (click)="checkAndProceed()">Continue</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The only thing I want to do is to add validation - that's all. None of the guides helped. Can we do in-html validation or ts validation? It would be nice to call validation when clicking 'Continue' button and making it valid if it is so.

In this case of validation I additionally get console error:
`Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of attributes on input elements. We have name, Id, and template reference variable. Your code is missing the template reference variable. It is the template reference variable that holds onto the reference to the element and has the valid, dirty, and other flags associated with it.

For example, change your code to include a template reference variable like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input required minlength="4" type="text"
           id="firstName"
           [(ngModel)]="user.firstName" name="firstName"
           #firstNameVar="ngModel">
    <small *ngIf="!firstNameVar.valid">Not valid!</small>
</div>
```

Notice the `#firstNameVar`. That is the template reference variable. It can be named the same thing as your Id and name attributes. I just named it something different so it could be readily distinguished between the other two attributes.

Notice also that the *ngIf is then changed to use `firstNameVar.valid`

For more information on template reference variables, see this: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars